# How to count matching records using a subquery in C# TableAdapter wizard

Tags: c#, sql, subquery

I have two tables for songs. The master table has an `ID` column and various columns describing the song. The second table has play lists, comprising `ID`s from the master table.

Thus there is a `1 to many` relationship between the two tables.

I need a query to return all the data from the master table, with a column containing the number of times each individual song has been used in play lists.

I have tried the following SQL query with a subquery for the count in Visual Studio's TableAdapter Configuration Wizard, but I am getting an error

> Missing or incomplete SELECT clause

```
SELECT SongID, Title, (
    COUNT(SongQueues.SongQueueSongID) 
    FROM SongQueues 
    WHERE SongQueues.SongQueueSongID = Songs.SongID
) AS PlayCount
FROM Songs
```

I'd like the result to be:

1 Imaging 5;

2 Bridge over troubled water 9;
...etc

Comment: You need a GroupBy instead of a Where.  See msdn examples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SongID, Title, COUNT(SongID) AS PlayCount
FROM Songs 
INNER JOIN SongQueues ON Songs.SongID = SongQueues.SongQueueSongID
```

OR
*Fields are ambiguous is my presumption*

```
SELECT Songs.SongID, Songs.Title, (
    COUNT(SongQueues.SongQueueSongID) 
    FROM SongQueues WHERE SongQueues.SongQueueSongID = Songs.SongID
) AS PlayCount
FROM Songs
```

Comment: Almost perfect - I had to add 'GROUP BY Songs.SongID, Songs.Title' to get it to work, and 'Count' the child ID instead. 

So this is what's working for me:
SELECT        Songs.SongID, Songs.Title, COUNT(SongQueues.SongQueueSongID) AS PlayCount
FROM            (Songs LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SongQueues ON Songs.SongID = SongQueues.SongQueueSongID)
GROUP BY Songs.SongID, Songs.Title

Thanks so much.